# Python DefaultDict Ordering Multiple Values Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sorting, defaultdict

I am trying to order all of the scores in order of each user's score from highest to lowest. I have attempted this with the code below:

```
import collections 
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

worker_scores = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.deque(maxlen=3))
import operator

worker_scores.clear() 

with open('score_names.txt') as f:
     for line in f: 
        worker,score = line.split(":")
        worker_scores[worker].append(int(score)) 

print("\nThis prints all the highest scores.\n")

for worker in sorted(worker_scores, key=itemgetter(1,2,3), reverse=True):
   print(worker," ".join(map(str,worker_scores[worker])))

   # This should print the maximum value for each key
   print max(worker_scores, key=worker_scores.get)
```

My text file also appears as follows:

```
AdamJohnson:10
AdamJohnson:20
AdamJohnson:30
AdamJohnson:40
AdamJohnson:60
AdamJohnson:50 
MichaelJordan:70
MichaelJordan:80
MichaelJordan:100
MichaelJordan:90
DavidSnowman:15
DavidSnowman:20
DavidSnowman:30
DavidSnowman:25
```

The outcome of the IDLE is as follows:

```
This prints all the highest scores.

MichaelJordan 80 100 90
AdamJohnson 40 60 50
DavidSnowman 20 30 25
```

This is what I desired, where the highest scores are at the top and the lowest scores are at the bottom. I discovered the `itemgetter` technique to do this so I have now accomplished part of my solution.

For the second part, I want the maximum key for each value to be printed. I can use the sorted key to print the keys in alphabetical order, but I cannot print the maximum value for each key. I have used this line from above:

```
print max(worker_scores, key=worker_scores.get)
```

To get this result:

```
AdamJohnson:60
MichaelJordan:100
DavidSnowman:30
```

But this error arrives: `Invalid Syntax (Max)`. 
What is going wrong?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Look sir, I am purely doing this code for my own benefit. What suggests that I am doing it for any qualification??? I do apologise but I feel offended. I have only been looking at other people's projects on SO to help develop my own program with my own understanding. Please do not suggest that I am plagiarising my own work as this undermines my own intentions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not enrolled in a GCSE qualification as I am already in college. I shall then delete this question and ask a new one. Apologies for my outburst, since you have apologised too, and I will take your comments onboard. Thanks.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava All you need here is using sorted function to sort your dictionary items then add to an `OrderedDict`, and about asking such questions i have saw that many peoples that have a repo more than 100K answered such questions also homework questions and ....! i don't think that this questions has much problem!!

Comment: @KasraAD Thank You. I understand his opinion, but when I am confused, it is evident that I will need help. I will re - edit the code shortly and I will notify you to see if it is correct or not.

Comment: @KasraAD I will briefly display this code and then delete all of my posts as I do not want other pupils taking this qualification to be notified of such ways to cheat their quailfication.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava there is no need to delete your question you just need to edit it and show us that what you tried for solve your problem!;)

Comment: @KasraAD sure will do!

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava : Please don't delete all of your old questions! We have **many** people asking questions about these GCSE tasks on Stack Overflow, so you can't blame us for being a little suspicious, especially when we see multiple questions about these tasks from the same person. I suggest that if you want to ask further questions related to this task that you explicitly state in the question that you are aware this is a GCSE task, but that you are doing it for your own self-study, not the GCSE.

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand, but now I will be unable to post any more questions due to the number of unlawful rating downs and also where it is perceived that I have cheated a qualification that does not exist in the area that I live.

Comment: You are using Python 3, in Python 3, `print` is a function `print(max(...))`

Comment: @KasraAD the question has been updated. Please inform me how to solve my problem.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but this is what is returned for each person: `MichaelJordan:` just nothing. No highest score. Just absolutely nothing. And the same happens for the other keys in my dictionary too. Would it be possible if you wrote your answer as a response to my questions as I am being restricted to comment on my own question (says please use extended chat.)

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava: Extended Chat is good! It will save a permanent copy of all these comments in a special chatroom connected with this question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you very much Sir! I do apologise wholeheartedly for any coincidence to a qualification assignment at such GCSE level. Please do understand that I have developed my own tasks to myself based on other posts across SO, so I will continue developing my quiz when time is available, since I have a vacation from my college this term. Thanks once again for your comments, and if I require your help, I will tag you when appropriate! Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe dear mr sharpe, I have researched the GCSE tasks online, and I have immediately noticed that the submission dates for these tasks is June 2016 to an assessor named 'Oxford Cambridge and RSA Examinations' . If I were a GCSE pupil, it would be highly unlikely that I would complete an assignment 1 1/2 years before it is due to be submitted, considering it has taken me 1 month to complete my program to the level of functionality it has today. Thanks again. Delbert John Nava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `max`, you can use `sorted` function and `collections.OrderedDict` :

```
d=OrderedDict()

for k,v in sorted(((i,j.pop()) for i,j in worker_scores.items()),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    d[k]=v

print d
OrderedDict([('MichaelJordan', 100), ('DavidSnowman', 30), ('AdamJohnson', 60)])
```

All that i have done in preceding code is loop over the `worker_scores` items and pop the last (max) element in `deque`,(`j.pop()`) but note that you need to use `reverse=True` to have the desire order, then add them to `OrderedDict`.

And for print the items :

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print ':'.join((k,str(v)))

MichaelJordan:100
DavidSnowman:30
AdamJohnson:60
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to print out your dictionary as `MichaelJordan:100`, `AdamJohnson:60` and `DavidSnowman:30` on my IDLE by using the following: `for worker in sorted(d):
   print(worker," ".join(map(str,d[worker])))` but this arrives: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. How can I solve this to print the desired outcome above?

Comment: Thank you very much sir! @KasraAD I do apologise for any inconvenience that I have caused in my code. I may need to ask again on SO but please do understand that I am not entering any qualification, and I express my sincere doubts that any child will be able to use such complex methods including defaultdict and arrays to complete their assignment at such qualification levels. Thanks :)

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava you're welcome! its OK such problems always happen for newcomers, also myself! ;)

Comment: yes my apologies, although I am now close to being unable to post due to the first comments regarding plagiarism and cheating, unfortunately. Thanks again for your help! I may require your assistance later! :(

Comment: I am surprised how your comment has been downvoted by 1, but I assume SO does not like this post.

Comment: @DelbertJ.Nava its not SO its a person that has not any reason for his down vote because if he (she) has any reason surely cared about comment! :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if I want to print out my dictionary in order of highest results to lowest results, I would need to use `itemgetter(1)` since I am looking at the second value, which has the highest score and then using the reverse property set to `True` in order to indicate that the dictionary must be printed with highest at the top and lowest to the bottom.

Please see [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value) if you do not understand. I have just found this answer.

Thanks again to @KasraAD and @AnttiHaapala, alongside @PM2ring for their support, and my apologies to @jonrsharpe. I have now successfully answered my own question!

This is the code:

```
for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print (':'.join((k,str(v))))
```

Comment: Plus for your commendable attempt!

Comment: @KasraAD may I just say thanks for helping me with the program. I have just completed it! Thanks ever so much!

Comment: @KasraAD two whole weeks and finally i've got there!! woo hoo!!

Comment: Really? two month? you should asked your question earlier!!

Comment: @KasraAD whoops i meant two weeks hahaha

Comment: @KasraAD please see my new question, it regards an issue in your method.